# What is jail breaking

Tags: ios, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the benefits of iPhone jailbreak?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149/what-are-the-benefits-of-iphone-jailbreak)

What is jail breaking? Why do people do it? What is the advantage and disadvantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IOS_jailbreaking](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking)

> Jailbreaking is a process that allows iPad, iPhone and iPod Touch users to install homebrew applications on their devices by unlocking the operating system and allowing the user root access. Once jailbroken, iPhone users are able to download many extensions and themes previously unavailable through the App Store via unofficial installers such as Cydia, Rock Your Phone and Icy Installer. A jailbroken iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch is still able to use the App Store and iTunes.

It is mostly done to escape the restrictive nature of the App Store. Once you have jailbroken an iPhone you are free to install a lot of software that apple would not normally allow. Such as modifying the lock screen to display useful information, or enabling multitasking on an iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreaking is to break out of the "jail" that Apple runs normal software in so you can do unauthorised modifications such as install your own applications or alter system components. Jailbreaking is often done by exploiting security issues in iOS and such are closed with the next software update.

If you jailbreak your iOS device the device is **unsupported**. While it's not illegal Apple has explicitly stated it's entirely your problem for any issues you cause. (The Genius bars won't touch a jailbroken phone unless it's been restored and the problems exists on a non hacked version of iOS).